Conda and Python Integration with C++: how to?
I'm facing an issue trying to call python code from a c++ application. I basically need to call python scripts and get the results, nothing too fancy.
I'm using Conda to manage my environments.
I wrote a sample application, that calls a python function returning python version. I expects the version to be the one of the activate environment (e.g. env1 has python 3.11.8 --> I expect the output ot be "3.11.8"). This works perfectly with python 3.11 environments, but when I try with a Python 3.10 env I still get "3.11", meaning that the c++ application is somehow binding to the wrong python interpreter.
Here's my CMakeList.txt file:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(MyProject)

# Find Python
find_package(Python3 COMPONENTS Development)

# Include Python headers
include_directories(${Python3_INCLUDE_DIRS})

# Include the 'include' directory
include_directories(include)

# Get all the .cpp files in the src directory
file(GLOB SOURCES "src/*.cpp")

# Add an executable with the collected sources
add_executable(main_executable ${SOURCES})

# Link Python libraries
target_link_libraries(main_executable PRIVATE ${Python3_LIBRARIES})



# Copy all the files in scripts in the build folder

file(GLOB PYTHON_SCRIPTS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/scripts/*.py)

foreach(PYTHON_SCRIPT ${PYTHON_SCRIPTS})
    get_filename_component(FILENAME ${PYTHON_SCRIPT} NAME)
    add_custom_command(TARGET main_executable POST_BUILD
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy
            ${PYTHON_SCRIPT}
            ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${CMAKE_CFG_INTDIR}/${FILENAME}
        COMMENT "Copying ${FILENAME} to the build directory"
    )
endforeach()

Here the main function (src/main):
#include <iostream>
#include <Python.h>
#include "pysum.hpp"
#include "staticYOLO.hpp"
#include "pyconfig.hpp"

int main() {
    // Initialize Python interpreter
    std::cout << "Init interpreter" << std::endl;

    Py_Initialize();

    // Check if initialization was successful
    if (!Py_IsInitialized()) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize Python interpreter\n");
        return 1;
    }

    pyconfig();
    
    Py_Finalize();

    return 0;
}

Here the pyconfig.hpp file and its implementation in pyconfig.cpp:
#ifndef PYCONFIG_H
#define PYCONFIG

void pyconfig();

#endif

#include <Python.h>
#include <mutex>
#include "pyconfig.hpp"

void pyconfig(){
    static std::mutex mtx; // Static mutex for synchronization

    // Lock the mutex to ensure thread safety during initialization
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx);

    static PyObject *name = PyUnicode_FromString((char*)"pyConfig");
    static PyObject *load_module = PyImport_Import(name);
    static PyObject *func = PyObject_GetAttrString(load_module,(char*)"pyConfig");

    PyObject *callfunc = PyObject_CallObject(func, NULL);

}

Last but not least, the pyConfig.py file, with the function to be called:
import platform
import sys

def pyConfig():
    print(platform.python_version())
    print("Python version:", sys.version)


The Python version is the version of the interpreter you linked with. It's not determined at runtime.

Hi molbdnilo, how to should I change the interpreter then?

You rebuild your application, linking with the interpreter you want (your application is the interpreter). If you want to use the "current Python" in the system, you need to launch that as a separate process and use some interprocess communication mechanism.
